# Running batch file for creating jar and execute the batch file through java code?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd

i want to run a .bat file in which command for creating jar are written and call that .bat file using my java code.My code is:

```
public static void main(String ar[])      
{  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\user\\mybatch.bat");  
}
```

and my batch file is :

```
@echo off  
jar -cf myjar.jar D:/foldername
```

the only problem is that, the `.bat` executes succesfully on double click and the jar is created but when i tried to execute it through a empty blank screen of cmd pop up but it won't execute the statement written for creating jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention the working directory as well, if you are not executing this java program from the same directory

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\user\\mybatch.bat", null,new File("C:\\user") );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you running the jar by opening the cmd then the jar will be created from where you are running the bat file not in the folder where batch file is placed , Suppose if cmd opens like c:/temp> in cmd then jar will be created in that folder only c:/temp> [image]